# Bind DatagramSocket to specific InetAddress but arbitrary port

Tags: java, sockets

Is it possible to bind a DatagramSocket in java to a specific InetAddress but let choose the system the port, like it is done when calling the `DatagramSocket()` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `0` as `port` number to `InetSocketAddress` constructor. You can then get real port number by calling `getLocalAddress()` or [`getLocalPort`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getLocalPort()).